# How to modify large text documents systematically?

Tags: text

I have a several hundred-thousand-line text document, and I need lines modified systematically. I need the file to be modified systematically so that it can be processed by another program.

At the beginning of every line, I need to add a string, and after every line of text, I need to add 2 more lines with text in them.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That sounds pretty easy with perl, sed, or awk.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (From your description, this looks as if it can be done in a few lines in just about _anything_ that's higher-level than C.)

Comment: You can't ask here for a tool recommendation, and we're not a code writing service. See the [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: Well, you *could* read the question that way but I prefer to focus on the first question asked: "How would I go about doing this?". That seems perfectly acceptable (neither a tool recommendation request nor a "give me the codez"). I'll edit it to try make it more acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about doing this?

You would choose one of the *many* standard text processing utilities, such as `tr`, `cut`, `paste`, `sed`, `awk`, and so on.

---

Assuming that you have an `awk` available to you (should be on *any* UNIX-like system (including "Bash for Ubuntu for Windows") and can be obtained quite easily for more "normal" Windows ([GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) in Gawk package, or [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/)), this is quite easy, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> ( echo 1; echo 2 echo 3 ) | awk '{ print "prefix-"$0; printf "111\n222\n" }'
prefix-1
111
222
prefix-2
111
222
prefix-3
111
222
```